# How to return IEnumerable type as object

Tags: c#, oop, ienumerable, var

I have a var (IEnumerable) which I wanted to return to a class.

```
public Myclass method(string str)
    {
        ...................
        var p1 = some data;
        return ?            
    }

public class Myclass
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public bool c { get; set; }
    ...........................
}
```

My intention is to return values through webAPI. To return as webAPI, I created a model class which containts the variable which I want to return through webAPI- that is 'Myclass'

Comment: `var` is not a type. It is a keyword telling the compiler to infer the type from an expression (`some data` in this case).

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, since the answers are related both to the keyword `var` and the `typeof` operator.Could you give a more detailed question of what you want to do?

Comment: Do you need to return different types in different cases? Is this your aim? As I see your 'method' returns Myclass object. question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, var is not a type, but rather keyword, C# is staticly typed which mean the compiler will run over your program and for each var decide what its real type

so to your question, you already know your type of some data all you need to do is just write it as return type (dont be lazy :))

read a bit more about the issue [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-1)

Comment: Yes I know the type, its IEnumerable<>. But how to return this as an object of my class?

Comment: @Sandy IEnumberable of wich type? why would you want to return a collection of some type as MyClass? does MyClass should/can hold that collection?
your method should probably look like:

 public IEnumerable<> method(string str)

Comment: 'Myclass' contains variables and this p1 exactly contains the values for that class. I want to return these values to 'Myclass'

Comment: just create new MyClass with the data from p1 and return it

Comment: @makc- 'p1' is a list from db

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26084/discussion-between-makc-and-sandy)

Answer (score 1):

Update to return IEnumerable type

```
public List<Myclass> method(string str)
{
 var p1 = new MyClass();
 return p1.ToList();
}
```

---

make use of [`typeof(boject)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which already available in c#

you can also do this `Type t = t1.GetType();`

After this you can get full name of type like this `MessageBox.Show(t.FullName);`

for you code it p1 should be of type `MyClass` as you returning it

```
public Myclass method(string str)
{
 var p1 = new MyClass();
 return p1;
}
```

**on thing to note down is `var` type varirable is get convert to the type you assign.**

[From MSDN `var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type. The following two declarations of i are functionally equivalent:

```
var i = 10; // implicitly typed
int i = 10; //explicitly typed
```

Comment: will you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Now you have the type, and then?

Comment: @CodeCaster - question title is misleading but i included all things what ever i got from op description ..

Comment: "Question" is: _"I have a var type which I wanted to return to a class."_ There's no use for `typeof()` nor the type's FullName.

Comment: @Pranay- In my case I want to return IEnumerable list whic is stored in var p1. So when I changed according to your code var p1 = new MyClass(); I am not able to store 'some data' which is IEnumerable. Hope you got my question.

Comment: @Sandy - if you want to rerun from IEnumerable list than it should be like var p1= ListEmp[0]; or you should change return type of you function to List<MyClass>.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is just a short hand assignment. `var` always has the type.

**`var`**

> An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you
>   had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.

You can return object. If you are not sure of the `DataType`

Answer (score 0):

@mike z is right in his comment: 'var' becomes the type of its assignment. So if you do this, it'll work:

```
var result = new MyClass();
return result;
```